# How to skip hidden a UITextField with IQKeyboardManager?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, iqkeyboardmanager

How can I skip a hidden `UITextField` when using `IQKeyboardManager`? Currently when I press the next arrow, it goes through every text field. And how to make the keyboard's next button go to the next text field?

Comment: uncheck enable for hidden text field

Comment: i cant under stand your question

Comment: uncheck enable for hidden text field. Can I post it as a answer and you accept it and other user also get help ??

Comment: on iOS keyboard, i have next button. When i press it, the keyboard dismisses, How can i make it to go to the next textfield?

Comment: Yes, you can post as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Please uncheck enable for hidden field and also place hidden field end of the list in story board.